# Cross domain DOM/JS pain

Tags: cross-domain

I have what I thought was a simple(ish) problem. I'm writing a SCORM package for an external learning resource. It's basically an iframe in a HTML page that the clients install in their LMS (Learning Management System).

The external resource needs to be able to tell the LMS that the user has completed the content. Because **the LMS and resource are on different domains**, there's obviously a JS security wall stopping me communicating directly. So when the user reaches the end of the content, the external resources sets its URL to have an anchor so the url goes from `http://url` to `http://url#complete`

Now I'm trying to get the location from the iframe and I'm failing miserably. I've tried `iframe.location` and `iframe.window.location` (.window is nothing too). I can't seem to get a handle on the right thing.

`iframe.src` shows me the original source URL, but it doesn't change when the iframe updates to the `#complete` version.

Any tips? Any alternatives? Although I control both pages, unless there's a javascript method to set cross-domain communication, I can't set the http header to allow it because I don't control the LMS server - it just pushes out my static page.

**Edit:** As an alternative, I'm considering storing the completed event in the session (a cookie would work too, I guess) at the resource end and then making another page that outputs that as a JSONP statement. I think it would be quite easy to do but it's a lot more fuss for something that *should* be simple. I literally need to flip one switch on the LMS code from the external site.

Comment: Just wonder why you can't simply put a button for reader in a frame?

Comment: @sinm Sorry? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/), it should make this fairly easy.

Using it you can do cross-domain RPC with no server-side interaction. The [readme at github](http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/#readme) is pretty good.